# emWin Segger parallel interface with ST7789

Tags: embedded

I have a display controller called "Sitronix ST7789". I want to drive it with 18 bit parallel interface(DB0-DB17). I searched emwin document for his parallel interface support with Sitronix ST7789.

I find the GUIDRV_FLEXCOLOR_F66709 parameter for it. Each controller selection supports different operation modes, but it supports only M16C0B8, M16C1B8, M16C0B16, M16C1B16. That means it supports only 8bit bus and 16bit bus and it doesn't support 18bit parallel interface?

Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Okey, i am new here.I will consider your suggestion.